# How to Split a String into two different elements in R?

Tags: r, csv, strsplit

I have a string like

```
c <- "Gary INMetro Chicago IL Metro"
```

I am doing

```
d <- strsplit(c,"Metro")
```

to get

```
> d[1]
[[1]]
[1] "Gary IN" " Chicago IL "
```

But I want two different elements and want to write to the csv file as

```
 City,State
 Gary,IN
 Chicago,IL
```

How to do that? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
read.table(text=gsub('Metro', '\n', c), col.names=c('City', 'State'))
#      City State
# 1    Gary    IN
# 2 Chicago    IL
```

Comment: That's really clever.  I like it.

Answer (score 2):

First step ist to unlist the strsplit

```
  d <- unlist(strsplit(c,"Metro"))
```

so you get single line vectors.

```
  [1] "Gary IN"      " Chicago IL "
```

Second you need to iterate over the vectors and trim your strings.

```
   trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
   for(i in 1:length(d)) { print(trim(d[i])) }

   [1] "Gary IN"
   [1] "Chicago IL"
```

Third you have to build a dataframe (complete code)

```
# Function to trim the fields
trim <- function(x) { gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x) }
# Dataset
c <- "Gary INMetro Chicago IL Metro"
# Split text rows 
d <- unlist(strsplit(c,"Metro"))
# Build an empty frame
frame <- data.frame()
# Split columns and collect the rows
for(i in (1:length(d)) ) { 
 # Split columns 
 r <- unlist(strsplit(trim(d[i])," "))
 # Collect rows
 frame[i,1] <- r[1]; 
 frame[i,2] <- r[2]; 
}
# Set table names
names(frame) <- c("City","State");
```

Result

```
     City State
1    Gary    IN
2 Chicago    IL
```

At least store it

write.csv(frame,"test.frm");

Comment: How to separate Gary and IN then? Any idea?